# Reset bios password of Asus Eee PC S101

Tags: laptop, bios, eee-pc

I have an old Asus Eee PC S101 that I forgot the bios password for. Instead of just throwing it away, I'd like to try to rescue it and maybe have it for my newborn son one day.

I'm ready to tear this baby open and search for a battery to pull, but maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: http://ccm.net/faq/1192-lost-bios-password-resetting-the-bios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from Asus Support and they confirm the only way is to remove the CMOS battery, but for 4 whole minutes, not just some 30 seconds.

In order to get to the CMOS battery, it is not sufficient to just unscrew the screws on the back of the laptop and crack it open, there are also four latches on the keyboard hidden behind F1, F6, F11 and Insert. This enabled you to remove the keyboard which is just the first step in a long process of dismantling almost the whole computer before getting to the CMOS battery.

I had to search for these latches for a long time and almost gave up when I gave a last googling. It revealed [this tutorial](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/replace-failed-keyboard-asus-eee-pc-900-laptop/) on changing the keyboard on a similar model. This tutorial showed me how they look and thus I found them. They are almost invisible on the S101s black keyboard and when some dirt comes in there they are actually indistinguishable from said dirt.

Answer (score 0):

Locate CMOS battery, and disconnect battery for 15-20 seconds, that should clear the BIOS password.

Comment: Maybe you should read my question, not just the topic

Comment: As to my knowledge you can only reset the BIOS in two ways: disconnect the battery (sometimes they are soldered!) or by short circuit two pins on the motherboard (if provided). As I am not familiar with this mobo in the S101 - you will have to open it to do it. so @GAD3R just did not put the comment to his answer that there is no other way.